LaTeX file not compiling at journal
After submitting an article to a journal, I received an email from the journal administrator informing me that some "essential details are missing" and requesting that I "share the files." He/she attached the following screenshot:
Does anyone know what this means? I'd uploaded the LaTex source file via the journal's website upon submission, but I guess it's not compiling on the journal's end. Everything works fine in Overleaf (no errors or warnings). Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Are you loading the stackengine package? Maybe the journal does not have this package installed. If that's the case, maybe uploading stackengine.sty from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine could help.

Welcome to TeX.SX! From the little information you provide, your paper seems to use a package stackengine.sty that apparently is not available in the TeX system of the journal. Locate this file on your machine, e.g. by looking into the log file generated by latexing the document on your machine (some line like (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stackengine/stackengine.sty) and upload this file together with your document.

Is "TeX Processor Log" a link to their .log file? If yes, please add it to your question.

No link, just a screenshot. I don't seem to have access to the upload page anymore. The administrator is asking for me to email the files, so I'll try attaching stackengine.sty.
